# kotlin with fastjson parse object error: default constructor not found

Tags: kotlin, fastjson

I am trying use fastjson parse object in Kotlin code. but exception happened when I use JSON.parseObject, here are detail:

My data class:

```
    import com.alibaba.fastjson.JSONObject

    data class StatesMessage @JvmOverloads constructor(val command: String = 
        "states", var states: States = States()) {

      fun toJsonString(): String {
          return JSONObject.toJSONString(this)
      }

      data class States(var x: Double = 0.0, var y: Double = 0.0)
    }
```

Then I try to get object from string:

```
val state = JSON.parseObject(s, StatesMessage::class.java)
```

But exception throw from fastjson:

```
Caused by: com.alibaba.fastjson.JSONException: default constructor not found. 
    class com.example.demo.StatesMessage
   at com.alibaba.fastjson.util.JavaBeanInfo.build(JavaBeanInfo.java:475)
   at com.alibaba.fastjson.util.JavaBeanInfo.build(JavaBeanInfo.java:221)
   at com.alibaba.fastjson.parser.ParserConfig.createJavaBeanDeserializer(ParserConfig.java:670)
   at com.alibaba.fastjson.parser.ParserConfig.getDeserializer(ParserConfig.java:587)
   at com.alibaba.fastjson.parser.ParserConfig.getDeserializer(ParserConfig.java:398)
   at com.alibaba.fastjson.parser.DefaultJSONParser.parseObject(DefaultJSONParser.java:665)
   at com.alibaba.fastjson.JSON.parseObject(JSON.java:365)
   at com.alibaba.fastjson.JSON.parseObject(JSON.java:269)
   at com.alibaba.fastjson.JSON.parseObject(JSON.java:488)
   at com.example.demo.StartupRunner.run(StartupRunner.kt:25)
   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:813)
... 5 more
```

all code refer to https://github.com/forest-yang/koltinjson

Comment: I run your code and it works fine, what lib version are you using and what JSON string are you parsing??

Comment: fastjson version is 1.2.49, kotlin version is 1.3.11, json string is in StartupRunner.kt. all code is located in github link.

Comment: fastjson latest version is `1.2.54`, I tested your String and got this output: `StatesMessage(command=states, states=States(x=5.0, y=5.0))`

Comment: it's does not work. would you describe your environment?

Comment: Kotlin 1.3.11, fastjson 1.2.54 and your code copied/pasted

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a fastjson (till 1.2.54) bug.
When I change to gson, it's work.

```
    /* it will throw exception
    val state = JSON.parseObject(s, StatesMessage::class.java)
    */
    val state = Gson().fromJson(s, StatesMessage::class.java)
    logger.info(state.states.x)
    logger.info(state.states.y)
```